# How to access DynamoDB web service with javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

I am trying to access DynamoDB with javascript via amazon cognito from browser. But i am getting multiple errors and i can't fin how to fix them.

```
<script>
    AWS.config.region = "eu-west-1"; 

    AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
        IdentityPoolId: "eu-west-1:...",
        RoleArn: "arn:aws:iam::..."
    });

    var db = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

    function readItem() {
        var table = "parklot";
        var date = "2019-07-17 08:27:27.524955";

        var params = {
            TableName: table,
            Key:{
                "date": date
            }
        };

        db.get(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                document.getElementById('textarea').innerHTML = "Unable to read item: " + "\n" + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2);
            } else {
                document.getElementById('textarea').innerHTML = "GetItem succeeded: " + "\n" + JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2);
            }
        });
    }

    readItem();

</script>`
```

This is the error message printed by the readItem() function :

Unable to read item: { "message": "Missing credentials in config", "code": "CredentialsError", "time": "2019-07-19T08:42:08.570Z", "requestId": "1953c431-aa01-11e9-9128-415a65efdf67", "statusCode": 403, "retryable": false, "retryDelay": 63.05053729604022, "originalError": { "message": "Could not load credentials from constructor", "code": "CredentialsError", "time": "2019-07-19T08:42:08.570Z", "requestId": "1953c431-aa01-11e9-9128-415a65efdf67", "statusCode": 403, "retryable": false, "retryDelay": 63.05053729604022, "originalError": { "message": "Access denied", "code": "AccessDenied", "time": "2019-07-19T08:42:08.567Z", "requestId": "1953c431-aa01-11e9-9128-415a65efdf67", "statusCode": 403, "retryable": false, "retryDelay": 63.05053729604022 } } }

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the error message you're indeed missing some credentials to access DynamoDB. 
You're not providing the AWS Access Key and the AWS Secret Access Key.
Check this for more info: [How to get started with AWS for Browser with Javascript](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/getting-started-browser.html).

Comment: This is question is about authenticating with Cognito, not with an access key.

Comment: The error exactly says that it's missing authentication credentials in the attempt at request. Be it with Cognito or any other AWS auth system. That's what he's clearly missing.

Comment: OP is missing credentials, but the solution is not to provide an access key id and secret access key. Cognito does not use these. This is not a solution to the given problem.